# How can I exclude $(this) from a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have something like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="#">A</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#">B</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#">C</a>
</div>
```

When one of these links is clicked, I want to perform the .hide() function on the links that are not clicked. I understand jQuery has the :not selector, but I can't figure out how to use it in this case because **it is necessary that I select the links using `$(".content a")`**

I want to do something like

```
$(".content a").click(function()
{
    $(".content a:not(this)").hide("slow");
});
```

but I can't figure out how to use the :not selector properly in this case.

Comment: try `!$(this)` for simpler code.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

Try using the [`not()` **method**](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not) instead of the [`:not()` selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not).

```
$(".content a").click(function() {
    $(".content a").not(this).hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: Why can I not get this to work... 

$("#menu-holder #first_level li").not(this).addClass("returnToParent");

Comment: @marck Without context, I don't know. Create a new question and I may be able to help.

Comment: This is a very bad solution (performance- wise). There is no real reason to `$(".content a")` inside the `click` callback... on EVERY click...

Answer (score 46):

You can use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) function rather than the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$(".content a").not(this).hide("slow")
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the jQuery `.siblings()` method:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <a href="#">A</a>
  <a href="#">B</a>
  <a href="#">C</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".content").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings().hide('slow');
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wTm5f/

Comment: You restructured the OP's code.  The anchors were not siblings in the sample code the OP provided.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the "siblings()" method, and prevent from running the ".content a" selector over and over again just for applying that effect:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="#">A</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#">B</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#">C</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    background-color:red;
    margin:10px;
}
.content.other {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".content a").click(function() {
  var current = $(this).parent();
  current.removeClass('other')
    .siblings()
    .addClass('other');
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3bzLV/1/