# How to select forms except those under div #target in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

`$('form')` is selecting too many for me,

how to restrict it so that those not under `#target` are selected?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

Answer (score 2):

The [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector is the one to use, however it might not be apparent with selector to pass to `:not`.

Train of thoughts: `form` will select all forms. You don't want to select the forms that are under the node with ID `parent`. Hence, these forms are selected by `#parent form`.

The complete selector would be:

```
$("form:not(#parent form)")
```

---

I concur with the other comments. The [jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/) is quite good and will give you the answer faster than asking here. The more you use it, the more you become familiar with it and you will find information more efficiently. Moreover, it will give you a better picture of how jQuery methods are structured and which ones are related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the not selector! Refer the [jQuery guide](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)!