# How would you use .not(this) in the case of the following code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, properties, optional-parameters

How would you say :not(this) in the case of this code:

```
$(".draghandle").droppable({
    accept: ".draghandle:not(this)"
    drop: function ( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
    }
});
```

You'll see the selector right next to the accept option is probably invalid, though I haven't checked to see, I was wondering if you might have a solution as to validating it? I have yet to find one, but don't be discouraged if you have a solution that changes another part of the code as well, I just need a fix.
Here's a similar question I'm trying to expand on: [jQuery: exclude $(this) from selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector/7813855#7813855)
And here's a link to the main code for this that I'm using as reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#accepted-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

You can pass a jQuery list as the accept argument instead of just a selector.  In the following demo, I make all `.ui-widget-content` elements droppable *except* the `#draggable` one. (reversing the original jQuery UI site demo).  the parameter I passed to `accept` was `$(".ui-widget-content").not("#draggable")`.

---

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/5TZ7b/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/5TZ7b/show

---

### Code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable, #draggable-nonvalid" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: $(".ui-widget-content").not("#draggable"),
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
});
```

---

### Conclusion

You can use the following as the parameter passed to `accept`.

```
$(".draghandle").not(this)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had no idea you could pass that as an accept argument. :)