# JQuery: How to select all elements with same class besides the one clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I guess I'm looking for an opposite to $(this).

If I have 3 elements with the same class how can I select only the elements I haven't clicked. EG:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

And I click the middle div, how do I only implement effects on the first and last element?

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not):

```
$('div.test').click(function(){
    var notClicked =  $('.test').not(this);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KGS25/ I have this but I can't figure out what I;m doing wrong?

Comment: @user1274383 what is the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.test').bind('click', function() {
  var not_clicked_elements = $(this).siblings('.test');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the ["not" selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Answer (score -1):

you can use this :

```js
$(document).on("click",".test ",this,function(e){ 

   alert($(this).text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">nicole</div>
<div class="test">charlize</div>
<div class="test">megan</div>
```