# Equivalent of jQuery's 'not' selector in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Working in D3.js, I'd like to select all the elements that match a selector *except* for the current element.

The reason is that I'd like to mouseover a circle, and have all the other circles with the same class turn light blue, but the current circle to stay the same shade.

This is what I have currently:

```
vis.selectAll('circle.prospect')
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
     console.log(d);
    d3.selectAll('circle.prospect').transition().style('opacity','0.5');
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity','1.0');
  });
```

In jQuery, I [could do this using `not`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector). Anyone know the D3.js equivalent?

Comment: have you tried `d3.selectAll('circle.prospect:not(this)')` ?

Comment: @ZoltanToth - yes, that doesn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: You can also use plain CSS for this, rather than JavaScript. For example, to fade out the other circles when hovering over any circle in the outer SVG element: `svg:hover circle:not(:hover) { opacity: .5; }`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An even simpler way to approach this would be using the power of D3's operators:

```
vis.selectAll('circle.prospect').on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var circleUnderMouse = this;
    d3.selectAll('circle.prospect').transition().style('opacity',function () {
        return (this === circleUnderMouse) ? 1.0 : 0.5;
    });
});
```

There's one difference here in that, unlike your original code, the `circleUnderMouse` element's opacity will be smoothly animated as well. If it's already fully opaque then probably not a big deal, otherwise you could use the [.duration()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-duration) operator in a similar fashion to speed the circleUnderMouse time to 0 and the others longer.

Answer (score 28):

If your elements have an unique CSS-accessible identifiers, you *can* use the `:not()` selector. Some potential examples:

```
d3.selectAll("circle.prospect:not(#" + this.id + ")");
d3.selectAll("circle.prospect:not(." + someUniqueClassFrom(d) + ")");
d3.selectAll("circle.prospect:not([uniqueAttr=" + this.getAttribute('uniqueAttr') + "])");
```

The reason `d3.selectAll('circle.prospect:not(this)')` doesn't work is because it's just literally saying to filter out any `<this></this>` elements — which is obviously not your intent, and since it's already selecting only `<circle></circle>` elements would have no effect regardless.

Even if you don't generally apply some unique DOM attribute, there's no reason you couldn't set one temporarily:

```
vis.selectAll('circle.prospect')
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    this.id = 'temp-' + Math.random();
    d3.selectAll('circle.prospect:not(#' + this.id + ')').transition().style('opacity','0.5');
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity','1.0');
    this.id = '';
  });
```

That said, however, if your elements don't already have an ID assigned already, I think Ian Roberts' solution is probably what I would do instead of this temporary identifier hack.

Answer (score 18):

You can `filter` a selection:

```
vis.selectAll('circle.prospect')
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
     console.log(d);
    var circleUnderMouse = this;
    d3.selectAll('circle.prospect').filter(function(d,i) {
      return (this !== circleUnderMouse);
    }).transition().style('opacity','0.5');
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity','1.0');
  });
```