# Select specific elements and change style of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

right now i am working with piecharts (d3.js) and have a small problem.
Each section of the piechart gets a label with a value right next to it outside of the piechart. When there are multiple values bellow, lets say 5 percent they overlap each other and the values become unreadable.

My values are generated with

```
}).attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d, i) {
    if (config.unit === "%") {
        return jsonChartData.dataRows[0].values[i] + ": " + jsonChartData.dataRows[0].numbers[i] + jsonChartData.unit;
    } else {
        return jsonChartData.dataRows[0].values[i] + ": " + jsonChartData.dataRows[0].numbers[i];
    }                           
});
```

the part that should be checked regarding its value is

```
 jsonChartData.dataRows[0].numbers[i]
```

Now I want to reduce the opacity of the overlapping elements, except for the highest one, to 0.4. I do not even know if this is the best solution (maybe the opacity of this elements could be changed when hovered/tapped on mobile devices?).

Since I am quite new to JavaScript, I would highly appreciate some help with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think changing opacity on hovering might work well for this. Attach this to your text elements:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    var currentText = this;
    d3.selectAll('.pie-text').transition().style('opacity',function () {
       return (this === currentText) ? 1 : 0.4;
});
```

Assuming the text elements have the class "pie-text". This would make all text get the opacity of 0.4 on hovering, except the text under the mouse. This is adapted from this answer: [Equivalent of jQuery's 'not' selector in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321352/equivalent-of-jquerys-not-selector-in-d3-js).

If you want to change the opacity back to 1 after the mouse leaves the text, you would need to attach a mouseout event as well.

```
.on('mouseout', function(d){
    d3.selectAll('.pie-text').transition().style('opacity', 1)
;
```

Using these ideas you could have the text hidden by default, and make it only appear on hovering over the pie chart as well, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: hi, first of all thanks! right now my code looks like this

.on('click', function(d){
    var currentText = this;
    d3.selectAll('#brm-piechart-labels').transition().style('opacity',function () {
       return (this === currentText) ? 1 : 0.4;});       
});    

i have changed the mouseover to "click" since it should work on mobile devices.
now whenever i click on one text-element all the elements get changed regarding the opacity.

Comment: Glad to help. Does your code work how you want though? I don't think it will because you are selecting by ID rather than class or some other attribute. IDs have to be unique to each element. Attach .attr("class", "brm-piechart-labels") to your text and then use d3.selectAll('.brm-piechart-labels'). If it works, nevermind, but I'm afraid selecting by ID could cause problems.

Comment: Yep, just realized that i had the wrong selector since i selected the parent element!
Now it works very well. Thank you very much!