# Select all DOM node of a class except one in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, selection

I am working with D3.js and actually I am trying to select all elements with a certain class except one on the particular event "mouseover".
I tried different kind of solutions, but no one worked or just partially.

This is my first solution:

```
.on("mouseover",
    function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
           .style("stroke-width", "4px");

        var selectedMethod = document.getElementById(d.name + "-line");
        var notSelectedMethods = $(".method").not(selectedMethod);
        d3.selectAll(notSelectedMethods)
           .style("opacity", 0.2);  

        var selectedLegend = document.getElementById(d.name + "-legend");
        var notSelectedLegends = $(".legend").not(selectedLegend);
        d3.selectAll(notSelectedLegends)
            .style("opacity", 0.2);
    }
)
```

Debugging I can see that `notSelectedMethods` store all nodes ignoring the not() function. This is true for the first part, because with the second one of the snippet work.
[image: snippet view]

Looking around I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321352/equivalent-of-jquerys-not-selector-in-d3-js), so I tried what that they said (focusing on the first part, the line selection), but no one work.

```
d3.selectAll(".method")
    .style("opacity",
        function() {
            return (this === selectedMethod) ? 1.0 : 0.2;
        }
    );
```

Or

```
var selectedMethod = this;
d3.selectAll(".method")
    .filter(
        function(n, i) {
            return (this !== selectedMethod);
        }
    )
    .style("opacity", 0.2);
```

Or

```
d3.selectAll(".method:not(." + this.id + ")")
    .style("opacity", 0.2);
```

How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

@TomB and @altocumulus point me in the right direction. With some bit changes, code are now working.

```
var selectedMethod = d.name;
d3.selectAll(".method")
    .style("opacity",
        function(e) {
            return (e.name === selectedMethod) ? 1.0 : 0.2;
        }
    );
```

I did not mention data structure of the `d` element, that's was my bad.
This snipper do the job. I think I cannot do better, am I right?

**UPDATE 2:**

I cheered too soon. I tried to replicate previously `on mouseover` solution on legend to change lines and legend (same logic as before)

```
.on("mouseover",
    function(d) {

        // Change opacity of legend's elements
        var selectedLegend = d.name;
        d3.selectAll(".legend")
            .style("opacity",
                function(e) {
                    return (e.name === selectedLegend) ? 1.0 : 0.2;
                }
        );

        // Change width of selected line
        var selectedMethod = d.name;
        d3.selectAll(".method")
            .style("stroke-width",
                function(e) {
                    return (e.name === selectedMethod) ? "4.5px" : "1.5px";
                }
        );

        // Change opacity of no-selected lines
        d3.selectAll(".method")
            .style("opacity",
                function(e) {
                    return (e.name === selectedMethod) ? 1.0 : 0.2;
                }
        );
```

I do not know why, snippet where I change width do not work (width does not change).

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@TomB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37678570/2296663) and @altocumulus point me in the right direction. With some bit changes, code are now working.

```
var selectedMethod = d.name;
d3.selectAll(".method")
    .style("opacity",
        function(e) {
            return (e.name === selectedMethod) ? 1.0 : 0.2;
        }
    );
```

I did not mention data structure of the `d` element, that's was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare the id like that :

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("stroke-width", "4px");

    var selectedLine = d.name + "-line";
    d3.selectAll(".method")
      .style("opacity", function(e) {
        return (e.id === selectedLine) ? 1.0 : 0.2;
    });
})
```

All items with "method" class will have an opacity of 1 except the one with id === d.name + "-line"

You can't compare JQuery items and D3 items like that, have a look at http://collaboradev.com/2014/03/18/d3-and-jquery-interoperability/

Comment: I hate these downvotes without explanation.. Here have my upvote

Comment: Just my guess, but this is most likely not going to work. The argument `e` will refer to the data bound to the element. However, the question gives no indication that there is any data available, nor, if there was any, that it has a property `e.id`.

Comment: Same result of other solutions. By the way I need that all items with "method" as class will have an opacity of 0.2 except the one selected with mouse (1.0 opacity). So the second part (legend related) work because I am compare two jQuery items?

Comment: @altocumulus's osservation and TimB snippet solve the problem. I will update ask with working code.

Comment: @lezan If you found a solution yourself, please don't edit this into your question, which often obscures the real problem for future readers, but rather post your [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).