# Compare input values using jQuery

Tags: jquery, comparison, each

I have a form with 3 input file fields.  I want to make sure that they do not upload the same document twice.  Right now my code is as follows:

```
$(':input.File').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == T) {
        $this.after('<br/><span class="error">Duplicate</span>');
    }
})
```

The code works but my issue is that it always throws the error because it is comparing against itself.  It identifies all file fields when I want it to compare all file fields but itself.

Is there a way to exclude the field being compared against? Essentially I want to check all the file field value except for the `$(this)` field.

Comment: I must be being thick but...where does `T` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know there is always going to be at least one duplicate, why not just allow one duplicate?

```
i = 0;
$(':input.File').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == T && i != 0) {
        $this.after('<br/><span class="error">Duplicate</span>');
    }

    i++;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an empty array, then go through each field and check if that field is in the array if not add it.

```
var arr = [];

$(':input.File').each(function(){
    if(arr.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1){
        $(this).after("<br/><span class='error'>Duplicate</span> ");
    }else{
        arr.push($(this).val());
    }
})
```

Comment: Why the downvote? +1 to compensate, since it's actually what I suggested but with an array

Comment: @JuanMendes I was wondering the same thing, but it's gone now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map to keep track of what values exist

```
(function(){
  var exists = {};
  $(':input.File').each(function() {
    if(exists[$(this).val()]){
      $this.after("<br/><span class='error'>Duplicate</span> ");
    } else {
      exists[$(this).val()] = true;
    }
  });
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is what you are looking for:

[jQuery: exclude $(this) from selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector)

In order to give you a more specific answer, I'd need a bit more code context.  (IE. what is T, how it that code reached, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

For a checkup after each user action:

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
     $('input[type=file][value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').not(this).after("<br/><span class='error'>Duplicate</span> ");
});
```