# Jquery - select a class that is not my selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selector like this:

```
$(this).next('.sub-menu');
```

I'm doing some stuff with it, and then I want to do some stuff with all .sub-menu's that are not this submenu. I know I can use :not somehow, but I can't figure out exactly how to word it.

Something like this I'm guessing:

```
$('.sub-menu):not(this).next('.sub-menu')
```

But that syntax isn't valid. How do I do this?

Comment: `$('.sub-menu).not(this).next('.sub-menu')`

Comment: `$('.sub-menu').not(this).next('.sub-menu')`

Comment: I think you are missing a single quote in the sub-menu selection? it should be $('.sub-menu' ) instead of $('.sub-menu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: exclude $(this) from selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to put the submenu you are working with into a variable like so:

```
var currentMenu = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
```

Then you can select the rest of the submenus doing this:

```
$('.sub-menu').not(currentMenu);
```

[More info about the not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery method `.siblings()`

For example if I have 5 `<p>` and I have one of them selected, to get all the other ones I need to do this:

#### HTML

```
<p>me</p>
<p>me</p>
<p class="start">not me</p>
<p>me</p>
<p>me</p>
```

#### JS

```
$(function() {

    var $this = $('p.start');

    var $siblings = $this.siblings();

    $siblings.css('color', 'red');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ubfca3uc/

Comment: depends if all sub-menu's are siblings of the current sub-menu

Comment: @Pete But surely if he is using `.next()` to move through them they have to be?

Comment: it depends what `this` is,  I would think it would be a link in an li tree structure - something like this: `<li><a>i think this link is this</a><ul class="sub-menu">`, in which case I wouldn't have thought the sub-menu would be a sibling.  Probably trying to show the current sub menu whilst trying to hide other sub menus - but this is all just speculation