# What is the appropriate selector for :not $(this)

Tags: jquery

**The above yellow link does not provide a solutions to this. The correct answer is `.siblings()` which is not in any of the linked solutions**

I am trying to select all `td` elements except for the one passed as `$(this)`. What is the proper way to do this ?

I don't think the following works :

```
$(this).find(':not')
```

..since I am looking for all at the same DOM level as $(this).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        
        $('a').click(function() {
          alert($(this).text());
        });
        
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <a>Apples</a><br />
    <a>Bananas</a><br />
    <a>Oranges</a><br />
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Just stating this to be clear that I am looking for a general solution, not one specific to this example.  :)

Comment: `$(this).find("td").not(this)`

Comment: Answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector

Comment: If they are siblings *(the same DOM level as `this`)*, i.e. all in the same row, you could just do `$(this).siblings()`

Comment: @adeneo - awesome.  `siblings()` is perfect

Comment: @CainBot - The solutions in that link, are invalid.  None of those solutions provide the correct answer which is `.siblings()`, which is now provided on this question.

Comment: @SanuelJackson - the accepted answer is perhaps not the best, but one of the proposed solutions does work, see here : http://jsfiddle.net/wTm5f/31/

Comment: @CainBot - yes, that works, but requires explicit specification of the preliminary selector, which I was requesting to use only `$(this)` for determining all elements at the same dom level. These are similar like apples and bananas are both fruit, but they work differently. The solutions are good for the pre-known element in fixed scenarios, where `.siblings()` is applicable for taking care of that unknown element while still remaining functional. In any case, your help was still appreciated, it's just not applicable to this question and was noted for others looking for this answer.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.not()` method to exclude a previous jQuery selection. You can pass a selector to it, but also an existing element or jQuery object.

```
var others = $('td').not(this);
```

```js
$('td').on('click', function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'red')
      $('td').not(this).css('color', 'blue');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell5</td><td>Cell5</td></tr>
</table>
```

[jQuery.not() reference](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

After seeing your update and the various comments, I start to think that you just want to get the siblings of `this`. If you just want an element's siblings, use jQuery's [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function. This function optionally accepts a selector to get only specific siblings. Anyway, siblings implicitly excludes `this` itself.

```js
$('td').on('click', function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'red')
      $(this).siblings().css('color', 'blue');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell5</td><td>Cell5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Should just be able to use `this` over `$(this)` - either way +1

Comment: @tymeJV You're right. That's even cleaner. I changed it.

Comment: would this work with something like >  `$($(this).parent()).not(this);`  .. update: nope.   how can i use it without having to know the current dom selection level.

Comment: TY for the update.    `.siblings()`  was the correct answer.