# How to do: "select all other elements, except this one"

Tags: jquery

I have 6 cards for testimonials for our website. The cards consist of a little bit of info and a "read more" button if you want to read the whole story. The card does expand but I want it to close the other cards.

I have tried the .not element but I can't find where to put it and it doesn't seem to work

```js
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery('.readmore').click(function(){  
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass('uitgeklapt');
  jQuery(this).parent().not(this).addClass('weg');
});
```

```css
.uitgeklapt {
  width:100%;
  height:530px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart left">
  <img class="image" src="https://checkbuster.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/BA-Group-1.png">
  <p class="tekst">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
  <p class="readmore">Read more</p>
  <p class="sluiten">Close</p>
</div>
```

I expect that when one presses "Read more" It adds a class to the other divs with a "display none."

EDIT:

I have added

```
jQuery('.readmore').click(function(){  
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass('uitgeklapt');
  jQuery(".cart").not($(this).parent()).addClass('weg');
  });
```

Yet, it doesn't give the other cards the class "weg"

Comment: Hi @Bram Werink, i think you have same parent for multiple read more

Comment: Hi @Bram Werink, elaborate you read more div and explain clearly, we are unable to find which one is parent which on is sibling,

Comment: Explain like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/how-can-i-exclude-this-from-a-jquery-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite straightforward:

```
var $myOwnCart = $(this).closest(".cart");
$(".cart").not($myOwnCart);
```

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

---

This would also work:

```
$(".cart").not($(this).parent());
```

but I prefer `.closest()` over `.parent()`, because the former will not stop to work just because you added a level of `<div>` to your HTML for some reason.

Comment: I now have this

 `jQuery('.readmore').click(function(){  
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('uitgeklapt');
      jQuery(".cart").not($(this).parent()).addClass('weg');
     });`

"weg" has a "display:none;" yet the other cards still appear.

Comment: Ah the problem aws the dollar sign, which had to be changed to "jQuery" in wordpress @Tomalak

Comment: Ah, okay. Conventionally, `jQuery` is aliased as `$`, but there are setups where this is not the case.